# Use implicit differentiation to obtain $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Use implicit differentiation to obtain $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$.
$$x^2+y^2=16$$.

My Attempt:
$$x^2+y^2=16$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $x$,
$$\dfrac {d}{dx} x^2 + \dfrac {d}{dx} y^2 = \dfrac {d}{dx} 16$$
$$2x+.....$$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} y^2= 2y \frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Did you even try to google this before posting it? There are loads of examples that you can follow.

Comment: If this is an exercise in a calculus course, it would be *much much* more efficient to review **examples** in your course notes or read the **examples** in the textbook first. One does not learn such thing from nowhere.

Comment: and in fact, the *first* example in Stewart's Calculus for implicit differentiation is "if $x^2+y^2=25$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$".

Answer (score 1):

if we assume, that $y=y(x)$ we get by the chain rule
$$2x+2yy'=0$$

Answer (score 0):

To implicitly differentiate, you must apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{\rm d}{\rm dx}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\rm d}{\rm dx}(16)$$
$$2x+2y\frac{\rm dy}{\rm dx}=0$$
$$\frac{\rm dy}{\rm dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule. Here you are assuming $y$ is a function of $x$ i.e you have $y = y(x)$. It now follows that, $y^2 = (y(x))^2 = x^2 \circ y(x)$ and so by the chain rule,

$$ \frac{d y^2}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(x^2) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(y(x)) = 2x \cdot \frac{d y}{dx}$$